# Trying to determine if bot crawling my site is malicious - MJ12bot

Tags: redirects

My server is getting around 3,000 requests per an hour from a bot identifying itself as "MJ12bot".

The URLs its hitting are coming form a 301 redirect, and are invalid on my new web application.

Strangely though, some of the urls its hitting are at my login endpoint.

How can I determine if these requests are legitimate, or if i should block the bot?

Answer (score 3):

MJ12Bot is a [bot developed by Majestic](https://mj12bot.com/), that's designed to gather information about your site for their proprietary backlink checker and keyword products.

It's supposed to adhere to the `robots.txt` standard. There should be no issue with blocking it like so:

```
User-agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /
```

More info: [Do I really have to block MJ12Bot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93672/do-i-really-have-to-block-mj12bot-as-the-prevailing-visitor-on-my-site)

Comment: It just seems a bit odd that a bot of that nature is trying to access a /login endpoint, with random credentials though?

Comment: The robots.txt is not enough, you should inject the rule in the .htaccess please see the answer below.

Comment: @PatrickValibus If the bot is actually Majestic's bot, then it will follow `robots.txt`. Otherwise it's just a game of whack-a-mole to block it by user agent. Personally I think it's counterproductive to block by user-agent. If anything, you should be blocking by IP since those are harder to spoof.

Comment: I know for expérience that majestic doesn't accept a No for crawl, it will at lest recrawl with an IP, that's why i suggested both in my answer, user agent and Ip address.

Answer (score 0):

That does appear weird. It could be malicious users hiding their hack attempts as the bot, which does happen.

I ended up blocking the bot. After 3,000 attempts yesterday of the SAME URL being accessed I put my robots.txt to:

```
User-Agent: MJ12bot
Crawl-Delay: 120
```

That didn't help, it went and added 2,000 more attempts that day then I blocked it in Cloudflare.

The crazy part is the site it was trying to index only has 30 static pages on it. Not sure why it needed to access it 11,636 times in two days.

Since Jan 20th a bot identifying itself as the MJ12bot has accessed the same site 66,202 times.

[image: MJ12bot 11,636 Attempts in two days]

[image: MJ12bot Not respecting robots.txt]

Comment: https://mj12bot.com/ seems relevant to your problem/question. `robots.txt` is a convention, some user agents will just not apply its content or be able to override it by some specific switches. It is sometimes documented and done and purpose, see: https://blog.archive.org/2017/04/17/robots-txt-meant-for-search-engines-dont-work-well-for-web-archives/

Comment: The robots.txt is not enough, you should inject the rule in the .htaccess please see the full answer below.

Comment: I contacted MJ12bot owners and they said it was my site that was the problem, not their bot. So I used a Firewall rule in Cloudflare to block the bot, they also put my site on their don't crawl list after I kept asking how it was my sites fault they would crawl the SAME page thousands of times a day

Answer (score 0):

If you only put the bot you want to block in the robots.txt, it's only OK if you trust them to respect the robots.txt directives. Remember robots.txt is only an information not a security gard.

I you really want to block bad robots (mj12bot from majestic is only an example, please note that if you block mj12bot he also come from anonymous Ip Address) you need to block them directly in the .htaccess . Blocking them in the .htaccess (or in virtual host) will prevent them from using server's ressource.

There is the script that you can customize with other bot or Ip address if you wan't to optimize server's ressources.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^(.*)mj12(.*)$" badbot=true
#customize with Ip Address if necessary
#SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^192\. badbot=true

RewriteCond %{ENV:badbot} ^true$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=500]
```